# BTC = $ ... Does this have to match the sum I'm buying for at an auction?

Tags: multibit

very new, so this is probably silly but:

I want to buy some bitcoin on an auction, but the exchange rate on MultiBit is very slightly dissimilar to the rate offered by the seller on the acution. Will this interfere with the transaction on the side of my wallet?

Comment: If the price you're buying them for is substantially lower than the current [CoinDesk](http://www.coindesk.com/price/) price, then I guarantee they're going to scam you somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't experience any technical difficulties, receiving/sending bitcoin that you bought for $30 or $3000 won't matter to your wallet. Your MultiBit wallet will just tell you its best approximation for the USD value of your bitcoin, which may not be the same price that you got the bitcoin for.

As Nick said, make sure you buy the bitcoins at a reasonable price. Do your research and you won't get scammed. Compare prices to places like [CoinDesk](http://www.coindesk.com/price/), [Cryptsy](https://www.cryptsy.com/markets/view/BTC_USD), and [coinmarketcap](https://coinmarketcap.com/).